# Web farm vs Clustering vs Load balancing IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, load-balancing, web-farm

**Question:**
What is the **difference between Web farm vs Clustering vs Load balancing** in IIS?

For a simple web app, which one is the easiest to administer/configure for an ASP MVC web? application?

Also, does IIS come with build in Configuration, is there a GUI UI to configure the cluster/load balancing